# powershell compare 2 folders, copy difference and clean old files into second folder

Tags: windows, powershell, script

Requirement:

I have 2 folders A and B.

Folder A contains old and new files with some changes in directories and subdirectories.

There are several old files with directories and subdirectories in folder B.

I need to compare the contents of two folders A and B and copy all new or modified files and directories from folder A to folder B and delete in folder B all the old files that are not in folder A.

```
# Files in 1 but not in 2 should wind up in 3 with the same dir structure as occurs in 1
param(
    $Folder1path = "C:\Folder1",
    $Folder2path = "C:\Folder2"
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version 'Latest'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder1Path -Recurse | Where-Object {

    [string] $toDiff = $_.FullName.Replace($Folder1path, $Folder2path)
    # Determine what's in 2, but not 1
    [bool] $isDiff = (Test-Path -Path $toDiff) -eq $false

    if ($isDiff) {
        # Create destination path that contains folder structure
        $dest = $_.FullName.Replace($Folder1path, $Folder2path)
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Verbose -Force
    }
}
```

enter code here

Comment: It seems like you are just copying files that are not there already to mirror the directories. Would using robocopy with the mirror flag not work for what you're trying to accomplish? `ROBOCOPY C:\Folder1 C:\Folder2 /MIR`

Comment: @Narzard, yes, you are absolutely right. Thx! It;s work well

Answer (score 1):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

$dirpath = 'C:\'
$FolderName=[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a Folder Name','Folder Name')

$FolderName = "$dirpath"+$FolderName
if(!(Test-Path -Path $FolderName)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $FolderName
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $FolderName\OLD
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $FolderName\NEW
    Write-Output "File '$FolderName' created successfully"
} else {
 
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("File '$FolderName' already exists")
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Copy New .exe files in [$folderName\NEW] and Press any key to continue..."


$RefBase  = "C:\123\NEW"   #  'D:\apps\newfiles\'
$DiffBase = "C:\Test"   #  '\\share\Existingfiles\'
$Target   = "C:\123\OLD"   #  '\\share2\backup\'

$RefTree = Get-ChildItem $RefBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($RefBase,'')}}

$DiffTree =  Get-ChildItem $DiffBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($DiffBase,'')}}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $RefTree `
               -DifferenceObject $DiffTree `
               -Property SubName `
               -ExcludeDifferent `
               -IncludeEqual | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq "==" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $SourceFile = Join-Path  $DiffBase $_.SubName
        $TargetFile = Join-Path  $Target   $_.SubName
        $TargetDir  = Split-Path $TargetFile -Parent
        If (!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){MD $TargetDir | Out-Null}
        Copy-Item $SourceFile -Destination $TargetFile -Force
    }


Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue...to copy new .exe in to C:\Test"


$RefBase  = "C:\123\NEW"   #  'D:\apps\newfiles\'
$DiffBase = "C:\123\NEW"   #  '\\share\Existingfiles\'
$Target   = "C:\Test"   #  '\\share2\backup\'

$RefTree = Get-ChildItem $RefBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($RefBase,'')}}

$DiffTree =  Get-ChildItem $DiffBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($DiffBase,'')}}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $RefTree `
               -DifferenceObject $DiffTree `
               -Property SubName `
               -ExcludeDifferent `
               -IncludeEqual | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq "==" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $SourceFile = Join-Path  $DiffBase $_.SubName
        $TargetFile = Join-Path  $Target   $_.SubName
        $TargetDir  = Split-Path $TargetFile -Parent
        If (!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){MD $TargetDir | Out-Null}
        Copy-Item $SourceFile -Destination $TargetFile -Recurse -Force
    }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?